# How to Cross Compile Jack2 source code on windows using Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, jack

Currently I am trying to download jack2 source code from git hub and trying to build and compile it on windows. As I came to know that it can not be compiled on windows and to build/compile it, we have to build it using Linux by the process of cross compilation. Kindly help me how to build/compile it and run it.

Comment: I use https://mxe.cc to build Windows binaries on Linux.

Comment: You sure about having to cross-compile? The [windows readme](https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2/tree/develop/windows) says nothing about it.